# How to get the value from span element inside div that are set from C# code using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have an aspx file with span sections inside a div:

```
 <div id="child1container" runat="server">
    <span class="textclass" id="UserName" runat="server" ClientId="username1"></span>
    <span class="textclass" id="BankName" runat="server" ClientId="bankname"></span>
 <div>
```

Here the values for Username and Bankname are set by the code behind (using .cs file). Once after the value is being set by the code, I need to capture the value of username and bankname in javascript using document.getElementById.value. Could someone help me on how to get this value in javascript so that I can do some more manipulation after this. I know I need to use window.onload function, but would like to know how to get the value from span element.

Answer (score 2):

Typically ASP.NET controls have a [ClientID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) property.  That is how the ID will render in HTML.

```
<span class="textclass" id="BankName" runat="server" ClientId="bankname"></span>
```

Then in your javascript:

```
document.getElementById('<%= BankName.ClientID %>')
```

Comment: Ok, so how to get the value using document.getElementById here?

Comment: Added the javascript to the post.  Whatever you put in the `ClientId` field is what will render as `id` in the HTML.

Comment: Forgot my ASP.NET eval's  Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

var val = document.getElementById("<%=BankName.ClientID%>").value